# How to determine what encryption is being used a LUKS partition?

Tags: partition, encryption, luks, cryptsetup

What command can be used to determine the used encryption on a LUKS partition (all the relevant information, initialization vector, generation scheme, mode of operation and block cipher primitive)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If the decrypted volume is `/dev/mapper/crypto` then you can get the information with

```
dmsetup table crypto
0 104853504 crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 000[...]000 0 254:2 4096
```

If the encrypted volume is `/dev/storage2/crypto` then you get the information with

```
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/storage2/crypto
LUKS header information for /dev/storage2/crypto

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    cbc-essiv:sha256
Hash spec:      sha256
[...]
```

Comment: Why two different  tools for the same task: dmsetup is a [lower level tool](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/DMCrypt#configuration-with-dmsetup-tool) then cryptsetup.

Comment: @akhan That's just what I am used to. But `cryptsetup status crypto` can be used, too.

Answer (score 16):

**List the disks:**

```
lsblk --fs
```

**Then (used encryption):**

```
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdb1
```

**Or (used encryption):**

```
cryptsetup status crypt_sdb1
```

**In addition (kernel supported encryption and bench):**

```
cat /proc/crypto
ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/crypto/

#cryptsetup benchmark --cipher aes-xts --key-size 256 
cryptsetup benchmark
```

Comment: As far as i understand, when using `cryptsetup status <partition>`, the  `<partition>`s that give info can be identified by the type `crypt` when using `lsblk` (without options).

Comment: @goulashsoup thank you! that little piece of information has been sorely missing from everything I've just spent the last half hour reading through...